# Elements loading at a larger size in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, spacing

I've got a problem that only comes into play in Chrome. When I first load any page in the site the H1 and nav elements in my navigation bar come in bigger. When inspecting with inspect element I can see that my padding and margin are the same and what they should be but the elements them selves are taller and wider. It's a fully responsive site so when I resize the browser and a @media rule comes into play the elements go back to the size they should be. But if I refresh at an @media size it loads it at the wrong size again.

If anyone knows what could be causing this, I would be very grateful to have some insight.

Note: I've tried line-height: 0; and height: auto; to no avail.

HTML

```
<header>
<a href="index.html"><h1><span id="logo">Design</span>Basics</h1></a>
<nav id="nav">
<a href="principles.html" id="navp">Principles</a>
<a href="type.html" id="navt">Typography</a>...
</nav>
</header
```

CSS

```
* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;}

p,html,img,body,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,dd,header,main,section,nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

a {text-decoration: none;}

ol,ul {list-style-type: none;}

html {font-size: 62.5%; min-height: 100%;}
body {height: 100%; background-color: #eee; color: #ffe;}

body, p { font-size: 1.6rem; line-height: 150%; font-family: 'Open Sans',
  'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, nav a { text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'Oxygen',
  'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; letter-spacing: .3rem;}
h1 {font-weight: 700; font-size: 3rem; color: #444;}

header { background: rgba(250,250,250,0.9);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(190,190,190,0.95);
  position:fixed; width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 20px rgba(100,100,100,0.6); }
header h1 {float:left; padding: .8rem 1% .95rem 2%;}
header hr { color: #ddd; size:1px; width:60%; display:none;}
h1 span#logo { font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica,
  Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: .7rem;}
nav{ float:right; margin: .9rem 1.5rem .95rem 1rem; font-size: 1.6rem;
  letter-spacing: .2rem; transition: 1s height;}
nav a { color: #bbb; margin: 0 1.5rem; transition: .6s color;
  font-weight: 300; height: auto;}
nav:hover a {color: #ddd;}
a#navp:hover, a#navt:hover, a#navc:hover, a#navr:hover {color: #888;}
```

Comment: share your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't have any javaScript, but I'll try to add relevant code.

Comment: You can create a jsFiddle without JavaScript. It saves everyone who wants to help you the hassle of manually copying it over by themselves. Furthermore the code you posted doesn't contain any media queries.

Comment: i cant find any difference, tested in chrome and FF

Comment: Is it happening only on first page load??